# php Echo/printing a multiline string?

Tags: php, echo, multiline

i have a php file launching my exe. the exe does cout and the text is printed in html which is all fine. until i write "someline\n"; The \n breaks the output and i only see the last line. How do i print/echo text/strings that has multilines in them?

The current paste has \n commented out and my text prints fine. It looks ugly in the console and when i view source with IE7 (although i primarily browse with FF) the source is painful to look at. Here is my current php and cpp file

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo( exec('c:/path/to/exe/launchMe.exe hey lol hi') );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

const string htmlLine(string s)
{
    s+= "<br />";
//  s += "\n";
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    stringstream s;
    s << argc;
    cout << htmlLine("woot") << htmlLine(s.str());
    for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i)
    {
        s.str("");
        s << i << " = " << argv[i];
        cout << htmlLine(s.str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Perl-output to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407590/return-perl-output-to-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://php.net/exec:

> ### Return Values
>
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the [passthru()](http://php.net/passthru) function.

The [exec()](http://php.net/exec) function only returns the last line of ouput, but [passthru()](http://php.net/passthru) returns *all* output.