# Return Perl-output to PHP

Tags: php, perl, return, readdir

I want to return the output of a perl script to a webpage. However it only returns the last line.

Perl script:

```
my $directory = $ARGV[0];
opendir(DIR,$directory);
my @files = grep {/\.txt$/ } readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
foreach(@files) {
    print $_."\n";
}
```

PHP code:

```
$perl_result = exec("perl $script_folder $project_folder");
*some code*
<?php print $perl_result; ?>
```

Expected output (and what the script returns in a Linux command line):

```
test.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
```

What PHP returns:

```
test3.txt
```

What do I have to change in my code to get PHP to show all lines?

Thanks

Comment: `$ARGV[0]` would only take `$script_folder`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a linux command to compile a c program, from php script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136328/how-to-run-a-linux-command-to-compile-a-c-program-from-php-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [PHP manual page for `exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the [`passthru()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) function.
>
> To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the `output` parameter.

So one suggestion is stop using `exec()` and start using [`passthru()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) . However, that's nonsense. `passthru()` doesn't actually return anything. It may be sufficient if *all* you need to do with `$perl_result` is print it to the browser, and thus don't really need the output to be stored in a variable at all. But if you need to match against the output, or manipulate it in any way, you don't want `passthru()`.

Instead, try the [backtick operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php):

```
<?php
$perl_result = `perl $script_folder $project_folder`;
```

Or try setting the second argument of `exec()` to an empty array:

```
<?php
$perl_result = array();
exec("perl $script_folder $project_folder", $perl_result);

$perl_result = implode("\n", $perl_result);  # array --> string
```

Comment: when using `$perl_result = passthru("perl $script_folder $project_folder");`, then nothing is returned...

Comment: Great, those thing work! It's for testing purposes, so I don't really need to do more stuff with the output.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From [php docs](http://php.net/function.exec),

> Return Values
>
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function.
>
> To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter