# what does exec() return here?

Tags: php, mysql

Following is a query string to import database:

```
$query = "mysql --user" . $this->userName . " --password " . $this->DatabaseName . " < " . $completePathOfSQLFile;
$resultQuery  = exec($query);
```

The command executes fine. But what does `exec` function return? I need to make sure that the operation was performed correctly and return `true | false` accordingly.

Comment: You can store the output in a second variable like this: `$output = array(); $result = exec($query, $output); print_r($output);`

Comment: You connect to the server with a query? o.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Perl-output to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407590/return-perl-output-to-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

> **Return Values**
>
> The last line from the result of the command.

But note that you can also pass a third argument to `exec` which will be the return status of the command. Non-zero values are usually error states, the `mysql` client may use that sensibly. The manual has notes on various other approaches too, it's worth reading.

Comment: How do I know if `all is well` after the `exec` command is run? I want to return a boolean

Comment: linux system doesn't return boolean. It returns `0` for "good" and `1` or sometimes `-1` for "not good". So you use `$programSuccess = ($returnVal === 0);` then there is a boolean in programSuccess. Other things not to confuse the return value with are `STDOUT` and `STDERR` which get text written into them.e

Answer (score 1):

As Quentin said 3rd parameter of exec is return_var

```
 string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

mysql will return non-zero exit code in case of an error.

```
# mysql -u root -e "SELECT 1" > /dev/null  2>&1
# echo $?
0 <- returns 0 for success


# mysql -u root -e "SOMETHING WRONG" > /dev/null  2>&1
# echo $?
1 <- Wrong statement
```

Please note that if the file is empty , it will still return "0", since there is no SQL syntax error or wrong arguments given to mysql client.

So You can add this to your code :

```
 $query = "mysql --user" . $this->userName . " --password " . $this >DatabaseName . " < " . $completePathOfSQLFile;
 $resultQuery  = exec($query,$output,$return_var);

 if (intval($return_var) !== 0) {
   echo "error: ".$output;
 }
```